# C++ What memory order do I need for the atomics in this MPMC queue?

Tags: c++

This is my implementation of a lockless, waitless, multithread-safe MPMC queue using only atomics:

```
template <typename T, int32_t SIZE>
class queue_mpmc {
    T ar[SIZE];
    std::atomic_uint64_t start;
    std::atomic_uint64_t end;
    std::atomic_int32_t precount;
    std::atomic_int32_t postcount;
  public:
    queue_mpmc() {
        start = 0;
        end = 0;
        precount = 0;
        postcount = 0;
    }
    bool trypush(T data) {
        int32_t c = ++precount;    // this must be done before the line beginning ar
        if (c > SIZE) { [[unlikely]]
            --precount;
            return false;
        }
        ar[end++ % SIZE] = data;
        ++postcount;               // this must be done after the line beginning ar
        return true;
    }
    T trypop() {
        int32_t c = --postcount;   // this must be done before the line beginning ar
        if (c < 0) {
            ++postcount;
            return T{};
        }
        T r = ar[start++ % SIZE];
        --precount;                // this must be done after the line beginning ar
        return r;
    }
    int32_t len() {
        return precount;
    }
};
```

It's designed for SIZE to be a factor of 2 (32, 64, 128, 256, etc.) as in these cases it provides efficient wraparound on the underlying array using the modulus operator due to compiler optimizations.

I have been reading about atomic [memory order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), but I'm new to this and I can't figure out whether this applies to the atomics I'm using? The design does rely on the `++/--precount` and `++/--postcount` being before or after the `end++` and `start++` instructions (which are inside the lines beginning `ar`). That's it though, and that only needs to apply on the current thread, it doesn't need to sync between threads beyond what is typically expected of atomics.

Can I improve performance by specifying a memory order?

Comment: Two threads push at the same time, first one does end++ so will fill ar[0]. Second one then does end++, gets ar[1].  Second thread finishes first, increments postcount.  First thread still hasn't filled ar[0].

Now a reader thread comes along.  Sees postcount > 0, reads ar[0], which doesn't actually have a T in it.

Probably fix that first before worrying about memory orders.

Comment: Also, in theory at least, 2 producers can write to the same location, if a producer stalls after end++ for so long that other threads cause the queue to wrap around to the same location.

Comment: @tony, that's a tough one (the first one), any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a way to ensure a thread finishes some amount of execution before getting rescheduled?

Comment: The thing about lock-free is that you can't ensure/guarantee much of anything.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HP2InVqgBFM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other bugs are fixed, *most likely* `start`, `end`, and `precount` can all be memory_order_relaxed in all uses.

`postcount` is the variable that signifies that a value has been written to the queue. ie it controls the *publishing* of the value, and the *reading* of the value.

So `postcount` needs memory_order_release ("publish") in push, and memory_order_acquire before reading (ie in pop).

Maybe.